# Чем нужно воспользоваться что бы можно было проводить оплату через определенный кошелек в магазине игры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать магазин, в нем будут предметы, за реальные деньги, нужно проводить оплату на определенный кошелек, пускай это будет Qiwi, проверять пришли ли деньги на кошелек. Вообщем мне нужно информация с помощью чего это нужно делать, попробую сам разобраться, почитать, почитал статью на Habr про Работа с внешними ресурсами в Unity3D(https://habr.com/ru/post/433366/). Но мне кажется это не то, можете накидать ресурсов для прочтения.

Comment: советую api qiwi

Comment: Пойду попробую разобраться, спасибо за совет

Comment: `Unity3D` в таких вопросах вообще не приделах. Только `C#`.

Comment: Можно же в Unity3D запускать ту же самую консоль, для того что бы на фоне совершать операции, через сопрограмму ?